# Why are Javascript function arguments not stored in a normal array?

Tags: javascript

I need to join the arguments passed to a function together and return them as a string and I remember reading somewhere that Javascript used a special type of array to store arguments inside. When I tried to call `arguments.join("")` I got a runtime error telling me that there was no such method.

Why doesn't Javascript store arguments in a standard array using references to point to the argument names?

Comment: Because that's how ECMAScript is defined.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to convert to an Array to join. You can borrow the `[].join` directly. `[].join.call(arguments, "")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one of the ways in which `arguments` is special is that it does, in fact, refer to the parameters directly. It is not possible in JavaScript to do that with a regular Array instance.

```
function foo( param ) {
  arguments[0] = "changed";
  alert( param ); // says "changed"
}

foo( "original" );
```

Now whether that's a "feature" or not is clearly a debatable question; I can't recall using it for any purpose other than to create irritating bugs. The point is that having a plain Array instance somehow have that rather bizarre behavior (bizarre in JavaScript terms) would open up all sorts of weird issues.

*edit* — it's pointed out in a comment that one could make an Array instance with setters and getters that would mimic this behavior. It'd be sort-of hard to do that programatically in one's own code (in some general way, and not on an ad-hoc basis, I mean), but clearly the runtime could do it.

Comment: Sure it is. You could use setters and getters. No reason they couldn't have implemented this internally for an Array supplied to the `arguments` identifier.

Comment: @squint well you could *mimic* the behavior with setters and getters, but I'm not sure I'd call it the same behavior.  However I can't get too enthusiastic about arguing the point because it's such a goofy thing anyway :-)

Comment: Yeah, my point is that OP is asking *why* it behaves this way. You're saying it's not possible. Certainly it would be possible for ECMAScript to use Arrays for the `arguments` and still have properties mapped to indices, even if getters/setters didn't exist in the language syntax.

Comment: @squint yes, true. The feeling I get is that the Committee really wants `arguments` to go away entirely, and mostly because of `.callee` and its ramifications. I've never seen any material extolling the virtues of this particular behavior. I don't think it's going away entirely though; indeed, perhaps exactly what you suggest is what they'll end up doing!

Comment: Nor have I. At least the param/index mapping is gone in strict mode, so that's a start.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a design-error in JavaScript.

You can convert it to a real array like this:

```
var args = Array.slice(arguments);
```

or this in older browsers:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

Comment: What browsers allow your first method? Just tried it on Chrome and it failed (as I expected).

Comment: In firefox that should work. The safest is to use the second method though.

Comment: Interesting. On Opera and Chrome it fails. AFAIK it is not part of the  standard language, I for one will avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't call `Array` methods directly on `arguments`, you can invoke `Array` methods on it using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) because of its array-like functionality:

```
Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, "");
```